# Google Maps' "Nearby Transit" iOS widget doesn't work

Tags: notifications, iphone, ios, google-maps

I'm using the Google Maps app v4.11 that includes a Notification Center widget for Nearby Transit. The problem is that it *always* says that there are no transit stations nearby. I'm in the middle of San Francisco, so this seems wrong.

The Google Maps app itself works fine so it's able to access my location data. I have "Allow Notifications" and "Show in Notification Center" enabled in Settings.

So why isn't the widget ever returning anything?

Comment: The best thing to do would be to contact Google.

Comment: For me, it depends where I am. At the bus stop near my home, it usually gets it right. At work, it usually is off by about a mile. I wonder if it's due to the widget not having enough time (between swiping over to view it) to accurately get its location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and it fixed itself. In 4-5 days.